# Error on Tomcat Server : Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in string value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a problem when passing on Tomcat Server. The code works on localhost but throws an exception on Tomcat Server. Here is the exception :

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in URL [file:/opt/****/WEB-INF/classes/context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in string value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in string value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"
```

And here is a part of my context.xml :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:****.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
</bean>
```

And my file ****.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Do you have any idea of what doesn't work and how to solve this problem?

Note : I have masked some path or file name by "****" due to confidentiality issue.

EDIT : Here is the complete stack trace :

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in URL [file:/opt/pdsa/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/pdsa-portlet/WEB-INF/classes/pdsaContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in string value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in string value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbc.driverClassName' in string value "${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:259)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: is your properties file deployed in your classpath correctly?

Comment: Yes, my properties file is in the same directory.

Comment: show us your `@ComponentScan` declaration please

Comment: Do you mean this? (the base-package is the good one)
    <!-- Auto scan the components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.****" />

(I am new in java development)

Comment: Post the full stack-trace. This is likely to be a Spring issue, not Tomcat.

Comment: I have edited my post to show the full stack-trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution! The problem was because of the file ****.properties who had a bad encoding. The encoding was in UTF-8-BOM instead of UTF-8. After changing the encoding, the deployment works very well as expected. Anyway, thanks for your answers.

The issue is closed for me.